# Is it possible to insert one row in the middle of the rows when arranging the references?

Tags: jabref

when editing my references manually in JabRef, I skipped one paper, if I insert this paper in the bottom of the list , it is not possible to replace it to it's correct place ?

Comment: What do you mean by *skip*, which list? What is the correct place? In which order items appear in the bibliography (list of references) is dependant of the used bibliogrphystyle, with the older BibTeX system as well with the modern `biblatex`/`biber` combo. Please elaborate.

Comment: I am just simply inserting paper data in JabRef , how can I know which system old or new, I am using Dear @Johannes_B

Comment: To be honest, it might help to read some basic literature.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

"JabRef is an open source bibliography reference manager." So the list you generate using JabRef isn't styled. The correct place of inserted reference is determined by LaTeX. Don't worry about reference position on bib file just compile it.

### Long Answer

For example if you have a bibliography.bib file for references with plain style, your tex file looks like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Instead of WYSIWYG editors, typesetting systems like \TeX{}\citet{abh03} or \LaTeX{} \citet{lamport94} can be used. 

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

Result is:

[image: Plain Bibliography example]

On your bibliography.bib file lamport94 might be written before abh94 but they are placed according to your citetion placement, because of your plain style. If you used other styles you'll get different placement on your bibliography list accordingly. Check some basic documents if you still have problems with bibliography style. [For example Latex Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management) is a good place to start.